# Android Development: Storing data accross activities

Tags: android, multithreading

As mentioned before I'm just starting out with android development, having now got my head around moving from activity to activity. I'm wondering whats the best way to store data so that it can be used when needed on various activities.

Coming from a web development background, I'm thinking upon this a bit like having data stored in a session or cookie. Something that exists in the background and can be accessed when needed. (I am aware that you could also use a DB, but i would like to avoid using one if possible for this particular app)

For arguments sake, say i wanted to have a linkedlist of employee objects that was persistent across multiply activities. If i created said linkedlist in a worker thread, would this thread then exist for the lifetime of the application, thus allowing the data to be available to the UI thread at any point?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a object-oriented development view I'd say what you want is pretty simple:

On your MainActivity, the activity that is started at the beginning of the lifetime of the application, you have the LinkedList

```
public class MainActivity extends Application {    

  private LinkedList<employee> employees = new LinkedList<employee>();

  public LinkedList getEmployees() {
    return this.employees;
  }
```

In your second activity:

```
public class SeconActivity extends Activity {

  private MainActivity         app;
  private LinkedList<employee> emp;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.app = (MainActivity) getApplication();
    this.emp = app.getEmployees();
```

For small amount of data across your application you could use the [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) class.

Comment: This sounds interesting, what do you mean by worker activity though? Is this a thread running parallel to the main UI thread.

Comment: I was just corresponding to your statement "If i created said linkedlist in a worker thread".
The worker Activity is the one that is called when the application is started by the user (in this example)

Comment: Whoops sorry never noticed you mentioned what it was up top. So in this scenario the worker activity would have to execute before the main activity?

Comment: No basicly this _is_ the main activity. Sorry about the confusion, I'll edit it

Comment: Ahh ok. How hard would it be to do this in a separate thread, ideally i would like to keep the UI separate from the initial data setup.

Comment: you could have a simple class for the data setup which is 'called' by the MainActivity. This class `extends Application` as well.

Comment: Superb, from your answer and a few others it sounds like extending the Application class is the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

Your content should be accessible via ContentProviders, which retrieve data from either the web or from a database. All activities and fragments within your application can request data from your content providers when needed.

In your example of having a list of employees, the employees should be in an "Employees" database table, and your providers should be returning [Cursor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html) objects containing the response based on the SQL queries you put together.

For database access, please see [SQLiteOpenHelper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html)

For content providers, see [ContentProviders](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html)

This is not an easy subject, and there is a lot to learn, but if you work your way through it it vastly improves the quality of your application. See [this link for a tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) on this subject.

I would also be happy to help with any questions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but im thinking more of how to store it without using a DB. Parsing an XML file and dumping it into lists on the fly type of thing.

Comment: Yeah, that actually becomes much more complicated. Mr.Me's solution is closer to what you want, but that can have issues with race conditions, discrepancies between activities, and other issues, but if this is a simple act it could work.

Answer (score 2):

To store data you can use `SharedPreferences` for small data storage, like settings, DB for big relational information, or even files. In your case that depends on the data size.

But it seems to me that your question is more on how to access this data from different activities than storing it.

I would suggest you have a look at the [Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) object. This is usually a singleton than remains in memory as long as the application lives. Therefore you can load data and retrieve it from wherever you want. If you want to access from different threads just keep in mind to protect against concurrency problems and that would be it.

Comment: I've found this to be the best solution for sharing data. Use an immutable data structure for simple & efficient concurrency.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see you have a few options, but as you specifically say you would like access to something for the lifetime of the application, you should refer to the Application class, which the docs say

> Base class for those who need to maintain global application state

You need to specify the name of the class that extends Application in your manifest, this then gets instantiated when the application process starts, and you can be sure it's there whenever your app is alive.

You can refer to docs here

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html

As an example, you'd need to create a class that extends Application, such as:-

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    ...
}
```

And edit your manifest to include the  tag referring to the above class:-

```
<application ... android:name="com.fullpat.to.MyApplication">
```

Thanks,

Ryan

Comment: Thanks, the explanation of the application class really helps put all this into some context.

Answer (score 0):

Shared preferences is the common way of doing. Though it may not be so straight forward depending on your list. If you can adapt it to a StringSet than you are good for shared preferences without any data convection of your objects.

Actually another idea is to have your list as an object of the application class of your app. The application class can be accessed by your activities within your app and it is often used for keeping "global variables".

Answer (score 0):

I used to pass data as `Intent Extra` in the old days, but then I found a nice design pattern used in the source code of ReplicaIsland [Rep](http://code.google.com/p/replicaisland/) .

The idea is to use a Class as SystemRegistry and have your data as static objects in it.

It would look like the following:

```
public class SystemRegistry {
         public static LinkedList<Object> myList;

 }
```

and from any part of your app and activity. you just call

```
SystemRegistry.myList
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) for that, it`s api is very easy. Also, you can clean data on app close or something else.

Answer (score 0):

For your specific need of only keeping a list of objects, you could extend the application class and "store" this list there. In other cases, the use of Extras in intent between activities, content provider and of course sqlite databases seems "cleaner".